woocommerce_order_status_processing does not read $_COOKIE['myCookie']
I developed WP WC hook method and need it to take and read some cookie value in order to do some actions based upon them. But it seems it crashes just after it accesses $_COOKIE.
All the rest code without this line works perfectly fine. And the cookie $_COOKIE['theCookieName'] is there - checked three times.
Here is my code:
function my_woocommerce_order_status_processing( $order_id, $order ){
    if(isset($_COOKIE['theCookieName'])) {
        $order->update_meta_data('referrer', 'MY VALUE');
        $order->save();
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'my_woocommerce_order_status_processing', 10, 2 );

The line if(isset($_COOKIE['theCookieName'])) is where the issue occurs.
Now, if I assign a value to the cookie, I expected that my order object to have this custom field "referrer" set to "MY VALUE".
But, it didn't happen at all. What I am doing wrong...

You should give more context and better explain what you are trying to do… Where and when the cookie is generated? Why are you using a cookie? Why do you want to add 'referrer' metadata to the order? With the provided details and explanations, your question remains unclear. So edit your question please.
